# Tkinter stuck in GUI while playing mp3 file

Tags: python, tkinter, mp3, pydub

I'm a complete beginner in Python and currently making a GUI with Tkinter that can play mp3 files. just for practice.

I'm using a Mac, and the rainbow wheel that appears when a program lags shows up when I press the play button I made. And it doesn't let me press any buttons while the mp3 file is playing.

Can anybody help me figure this out please?

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
from tkinter import *

class MP3:

def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

    self.go_back_button = Button(frame, text = '<<')
    self.go_back_button.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

    self.play_button = Button(frame, text = '|>', command = self.play_song)
    self.play_button.grid(row = 0 , column = 1)

    self.pause_button = Button(frame, text = '||', command = self.pause_song)
    self.pause_button.grid(row = 0 , column = 2)

    self.go_forward_button = Button(frame, text = '>>')
    self.go_forward_button.grid(row = 0 , column = 3)

    self.shuffle_button = Button(frame, text = 'SHUFFLE')
    self.shuffle_button.grid(row = 0 , column = 4)

    self.is_paused = False

    self.song_list = ['songs.mp3']
    self.i = 0


def play_song(self):
    while self.is_paused is False:
        song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("/Users/bang/Desktop/music/{}".format(self.song_list[self.i]))
        play(song)

def pause_song(self):
    self.is_paused = True


root = Tk()
myMp3 = MP3(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can't provide a detailed answer but I would suggest using threads. You can create a new thread in which the audio is played.

Comment: I agree with scotty. You will need to use threading to manage the audio as to not interrupt the mainloop in tkinter.

Comment: I imagine that your program *'freezes'* because you're not just trying to play the file once, but you're actually looping as fast as you possibly can and calling `play(song)` many times.

Comment: @AdamMitchell that is another issue as well. The OP will need to correct both.

Comment: thanks guys for your comments. I'm not that familiar with threads and want to learn more about them and how to use them. Is there a good resource or way to learn more about threads?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using simpleaudio (e.g. `pip install simpleaudio`) like suggested in the [pydub readme](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#playback)

If you use `pydub.playback.play()` it will still wait for the playback to finish, but [`pydub.playback._play_with_simpleaudio()`](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/playback.py) will run in a thread and not block the interpreter.

You'll probably want to use the `_play_with_simpleaudio()` function as a starting point for your own playback functionality which uses `simpleaudio` directly

Comment: I cannot close tinker window while playing. Any suggestion?

Comment: Also _play_with_simpleaudio() takes an argument. I put the AudioSegment song.